# remove array component from object

Tags: arrays, angular, delete-row, splice

I have some compllex component  which contains array

```
this.SomeComponent.subArray

SomeComponent:model1;
```

model1 definition:

```
someString1:string;
someString2:string;
someString3:string;
subArray[]
```

model2 definition:

```
someString22:string;
someString23:string;
someString24:string;
```

Now if I console.log(JSON.stringify(this.SomeComponent.subArray)); 
I get :

```
SomeComponent[{"someString22":"one","someString23":"yellow","someString24":"water",},
{"someString22":"two","someString23":"red","someString24":"ground",}
{"someString22":"three","someString23":"green","someString24":"air",}]
```

Now my task is to delete `subArray` part which has  `someString23==red`.
So When I console log next time I must get only this

```
SomeComponent[
    {"someString22":"two","someString23":"red","someString24":"ground",}
    {"someString22":"three","someString23":"green","someString24":"air",}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: question solved, thanks to Aakash Garg and  Michael D. You guys rock! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter method like below :-

```
this.subArray = subArray.filter((item) => item["someString23"]!==red);
```

Comment: Hi Akash Garg, I've update question. I want to actually delete that part so after new console.log it must not be displayed

Comment: Aakash Garg thanks, so filter deletes component. Thats great. And what directive adds component to array ? can u write quick line of code ?

Comment: subArray.push(component).